# Which is the best way to get real time data from avaya cms server?

Tags: avaya, jtapi

I am sorry if this question goes out of topic but i forced to ask here as there is very limited resources found over the net on this.

I am looking to implement system to get real time data from avaya cms server I did lot of RND on JTAPI but it has got some limitations it is not giving all events all data as stored in CMS database. I also tried connecting cms database using Java but no success because it also give historical data in delay of 30 mins.

Is it possible to get the same technically using JTAPI,TAPI anything. Or is there anyone who have used any paid tool by avaya which is cheaper and can solve this purpose.
I saw clint but don't intend to use. Please let me know the ways if anyone had done this.

Answer (score 3):

Your CMS may provide a feature known to me as *realtime socket*. It is a service pushing data about skills/splits, vdns and vectors  over a network socket.

It is virtually the same what you'll find in hsplit and so on but realtime.

Pushed data can be configured by your cms admin.

If you are looking for call data you may take a look at *call_rec* table in cms.

Comment: Thanks Hajo Thelen for clarifying my doubts all the time. I would be doing some RND on realtime socket as this is something new i came to know about avaya cms, I will let you know accordingly.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use clintSVR which is a high level tool based on CMS CLINT. By using clintSVR, you can use CGI, OCX and C++ interfaces to get the real time data from CMS.

Comment: Can you please give me some suggestion on how to use this tool please.

Comment: Thanks i got the same from this blog, It seems that it's your blog.http://uwengkai.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/clintsvr/. I would be really happy if it worked. Could you please tell me some idea how i can import these realtime data to mysql database. I really spent many hours on this and was stuck now i see some way to do the same.

Comment: You can follow the installation steps to install the clintSVR first. The server has three interfaces for you to get real time data. You can use one of the interface to get real time data, then insert the data to your mysql database.

Comment: clintSVR also supports database logging, you can find your real time data directly from popular database such as MySQL, mssql and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can get this from realtime reports. You'll need to scrape them.

RT socket is just a set of wrappers around clint for running reports. It takes the realtime report data and sends to to a socket.

You can roll your own real time reports with clint and feed that to whatever needs to ship the data. A sample realtime report can be run from the command line like:

```
/cms/toolsbin/clint -u your_user <<EXECUTE_DONE
do menu 0 "cu:rea:Meas"
do "Run"
do "Exit"
EXECUTE_DONE
```

Here is an example of running a report directly
Run report directly:

```
/cms/toolsbin/clint -u ini <<EXECUTE_DONE
clear
run gem "r_custom/cr_r_3"
do "Run"
do "Exit"
EXECUTE_DONE
```